# I got Errors in C++ when try to use modules from python scripts

Tags: python, c++

I have a python script that read IMU data from the sensor.  This is the python script:

```
import Microcontroller_Manager_Serial as Serial
import Microcontroller_Manager_Bluetooth as Bluetooth

## Function which get the current accelerometer full-scale value
def IMU_Get_Accelerometer_Full_Scale(communication_mode):
    data_out = [81, 58, 0, 58, 13, 10]
    data_in = [48]
    current_data_size = 10
    current_time_out = 0.5
    if (communication_mode == 2):
        Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Send_Data(bytes(data_out))
        data_in = Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    else:
       Serial.Serial_Port_Send_Data(data_out)
       data_in = Serial.Serial_Port_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    return data_in

## Function which set the current accelerometer full-scale value
def IMU_Set_Accelerometer_Full_Scale(communication_mode,choice):

    data_out = [81, 58, 1, 58, choice, 58, 13, 10]
    data_in = [48]
    current_data_size = 10
    current_time_out = 0.5
    if (communication_mode == 2):
       Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Send_Data(bytes(data_out))
       data_in = Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    else:
       Serial.Serial_Port_Send_Data(data_out)
       data_in = Serial.Serial_Port_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    return data_in

## Function which get the current gyroscope full-scale value
def IMU_Get_Gyroscope_Full_Scale(communication_mode):
    data_out = [82, 58, 0, 58, 13, 10]
    data_in = [48]
    current_data_size = 10
    current_time_out = 0.5
    if (communication_mode == 2):
       Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Send_Data(bytes(data_out))
       data_in = Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    else:
       Serial.Serial_Port_Send_Data(data_out)
       data_in = Serial.Serial_Port_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    return data_in

## Function which set the current gyroscope full-scale value
def IMU_Set_Gyroscope_Full_Scale(communication_mode,choice):

    data_out = [82, 58, 1, 58, choice, 58, 13, 10]
    data_in = [48]
    current_data_size = 10
    current_time_out = 0.5
    if (communication_mode == 2):
       Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Send_Data(bytes(data_out))
       data_in = Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    else:
      Serial.Serial_Port_Send_Data(data_out)
      data_in = Serial.Serial_Port_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    return data_in

## Function which get measurement from the IMU sensor
def IMU_Get_Values(communication_mode,choice):
    data_out = [83, 58, choice, 58, 13, 10]
    data_in = [48]
    current_data_size = 30
    current_time_out = 0.5
    if (communication_mode == 2):
       Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Send_Data(bytes(data_out))
       data_in = Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    else:
       Serial.Serial_Port_Send_Data(data_out)
       data_in = Serial.Serial_Port_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    return data_in

## Function which get the sensivity adjustment parameters for the magnetometer
def IMU_Get_Magnetometer_Parameters(communication_mode):
    data_out = [84, 13, 10]
    data_in = [48]
    current_data_size = 10
    current_time_out = 0.5
    if (communication_mode == 2):
       Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Send_Data(bytes(data_out))
       data_in = Bluetooth.Bluetooth_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    else:
       Serial.Serial_Port_Send_Data(data_out)
       data_in = Serial.Serial_Port_Receive_Data(current_data_size,current_time_out)
    return data_in
```

So from that python Script I need a C++ code that can ask for IMU data update and publish it. This is my C++ code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

export module Microcontroller_Manager_Serial.Serial;
int Communication_Mode_ = 0;
double data_recieved=0;

int main()
{

int serial_port = serialOpen ("/dev/serial0", 115200);
if (serial_port > 0 ) {

data_recieved = IMU.IMU_Get_Values(1, 1)
printf("Raw data received: ", data_received)

}
}
```

But I got the following errors:

```
get_data_test.cpp:5:8: error: ‘module’ does not name a type; did you
mean ‘double’?  export module Microcontroller_Manager_Serial.Serial;
        ^~~~~~
        double get_data_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: get_data_test.cpp:20:20: error: ‘IMU’ was not declared in this scope
    data_recieved = IMU.IMU_Get_Values(1, 1)
```

Any help?

Comment: Try adding an additional include `#include <Python.h>` Also consult this on the topic of embedding pyhton into other apps. https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

Comment: It looks like you expect your C++ code and Python to automatically work together. They don't; you can't import Python modules into C++ or vice versa.